# iOS 10 Beta Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The stack exchange app crashes when I hit any back button.

- App Version: 1.5.1.2
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5261v)

Comment: How did you get 10.0?

Comment: I'll investigate.  It looks like a race on a KVObserver.

Comment: I'm an Apple developer so I get the betas so I can test my apps @Alex

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in 1.5.2.

The view controller owned an object with a weak reference to the table view that was also observing the table view's contentOffset. In iOS 9 and earlier, the observer was deallocated before the table view, now it looks like the order's reversed, triggering a KVO crash. Switching to a strong reference fixes this.